# Phrase for the opposite of "foolproof"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a concise way to describe something that is poorly designed, such that users are likely to accidentally make errors when using it? I'm looking for pretty much an exact antonym for "foolproof".

As an example, suppose there's a UI for job management that allows jobs to be canceled. When the "Cancel" button is clicked, a dialog appears saying "Canceling will lose job progress. Do you want to let the job finish? [Yes] / [No]" Clicking "No" will actually abort the job. The UI is working as designed, but since many users will not read the full message and assume that the opposite question is being asked, they are likely to use it incorrectly and mistakenly choose the wrong option. The UI itself works as intended and is not *directly* failing or causing the error, but its design is causing *others* to make mistakes.

I'd like a concise yet generalizable way to say, "**This UI is** *[likely to be the cause of frequent user error].*" So far the best word that I have is "confusing" but I'd like something stronger and more specific.

"Error-prone" is close, but I feel like that more strongly means "liable to *make* mistakes" instead of "*cause* mistakes to be made."

I'm not satisfied with the following words, because they suggest a defect of implementation (that it can fail even if used "correctly") and don't sufficiently convey an error-causing design: "defective", "faulty", "flawed", "imperfect", "undependable", "unreliable", "fallible"

I would also like to avoid direct or implicit criticism of the creator, so I don't want to say "poorly designed."

Comment: You say that you'd "like to avoid direct or implicit criticism of the creator" but the UI is poorly designed, so any way of saying that _is_ an implicit criticism of the creator. It was their job to get it right and they failed. You can certainly avoid making it personal but you can't remove the criticism.

Comment: @KannE is right; just describe why it's confusing rather than try to come up with a generic adjective. Also, [ui.SE] might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @KillingTime I don't agree that criticism of a person and their work are necessarily inseparable. In many workplaces, work is reviewed by others. I certainly wouldn't tell anyone I wanted to maintain a working relationship with that they _failed_ when I found an issue with their work.

Comment: @JustinLardinois If you tell someone that there is a flaw in the work that they produced then there _is_ an implied criticism of the quality of their work. You can word it to try and avoid it being personal and hurtful but the only way to completely avoid that implication is to avoid mentioning the flaw altogether.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is more familiarity with the language of design, i.e. rather than one particular word you'd like to be able to have a good language for specific sorts of design flaws (this also addresses your concern about being sensitive to the creator of the UI: you will be able to offer actionable rather than vague criticism). You might like to consult Norman's "The Design of Everyday Things". He identifies a lot of useful concepts like "constraints", "affordances", etc. I'm not sure what specifically applies to your yes/no example, but agree with your intuition there

Answer (score 25):

This UI is:
 - Nonobvious = [Not easily discovered, seen, or understood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonobvious)
 - Unclear = [not clear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unclear)
 - Counterintuitive = [contrary to what one would intuitively expect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterintuitive)
 - Illogical = [not observing the principles of logic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illogical)

It is difficult to correct someone without risking direct or implicit criticism.

Comment: "Counter-intuitive" would seem to be a very good fit.

Comment: Yes -- counter intuitive does sound right.

Answer (score 18):

***foolprone***

> something or someone that is at high risk of foolish actions or ideas being brought upon them and cannot become rid of such actions or ideas, no matter the nature of foolishness; antonym of foolproof.

(courtesy of https://definithing.com/foolprone/ & https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=foolprone)

Arguably, it's a made-up word, but it [*does* exist in the wild](https://books.google.pl/books?id=1oN8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=%22foolprone%22&source=bl&ots=1Db_n6cJop&sig=ACfU3U2HpV-OppJe-gghiKEVnZRrMI9DKw&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwignaG2v_DhAhVyo4sKHSuAAt4Q6AEwA3oECC8QAQ), and it nice enough as far as neologisms go IMVHO.

Comment: Please add the definition to your answer. Also note that all words are made up. ;)

Comment: @JJJ fixed, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 17):

> Misleading

*Giving the wrong idea or impression* - [OOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misleading)

A confirmation pop-up is expected to ask if the user wants to continue.  When it asks the negation of what is expected many people can be expected to answer incorrectly.

Comment: [ISN’T IT CONFUSING? YES, IT ISN’T.](https://www.dimensionsofculture.com/2011/03/isnt-it-confusing-yes-it-isnt/)

Comment: I would add "_deliberately_ misleading" in cases when, for example, trying to decline software the OS vendor is pushing.

Answer (score 10):

Probably not very common outside of programming circles, but a "**footgun**" is something which makes it very easy for the user to shoot themselves in the foot. It is fairly negative towards the feature, but other than that it doesn't criticize the creator (as far as I'm aware).

From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun :

> (programming slang, humorous, derogatory) Any feature whose addition to a product results in the user shooting themselves in the foot.

Answer (score 5):

I read the title of the question and immediately thought of **error prone**—before reading the rest of the question. I *personally* don't think there is a better phrase than that. It's open to interpretation and context what the reason is behind the possible errors.

---

Having said that, another possible word is [**fallible**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallible):

> **1** : liable to be erroneous
>   // a *fallible* generalization
>   **2** : capable of making a mistake
>   // we're all *fallible*

In short:

> The UI is *fallible*.

Comment: Isn't it more a case that the UI leads the *user* to be more fallible? Error prone may be better.

Comment: @JamesRandom I did say that *error prone* seems like the best choice. ;) But the problem with the question comes from the source of the error. If the question doesn't want to admit poor design *or* user error (of any kind), it's not clear what the opposite of *foolproof* could possibly be—because *something* has to produce an error of some kind . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford Actually I came here to write *error prone* as an answer, turned out you already mentioned that in this comment. You should add that as an answer!

Comment: @justhalf It *is* in my answer. In the first paragraph. ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that. Perhaps make it bold and link to definition, like you did for fallible?

Comment: "Fallible" is definitely not right. It describes something that makes mistakes, not something that causes mistakes -- exactly the problem the OP claims with "error-prone".

Answer (score 5):

**error-inducing**

> Let’s stop putting the blame in the wrong place. Interfaces should be
> designed to help humans achieve their goals, but also to avoid doing
> stupid things. Alan Cooper refers to “error-inducing design”, which is
> design that basically encourages error because it fails to consider
> human limitations ([by Antony Adelaar](https://www.mindtheproduct.com/lets-stop-talking-about-human-error-its-your-product/)).

(Quote refers to [Alan Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Cooper), the American software designer.)

In this case, presumption would be a *human limitation*. I would [presume](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823025914/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/assume-or-presume) (ODO) that a confirmation dialog box would have this basic setup: Perform requested action? [yes/confirm] [no/cancel]. But if I clicked on *abort job* by accident, ignored the dialog (based on my presumption), and clicked *no*, that would perform the action (i.e., abort the job), which could be a *destructive action.* Or so I presume, based on a likely purpose of confirmation dialog boxes--preventing, as possible, "unintended havoc" ([Designing Confirmation](https://medium.com/nextux/designing-confirmation-278d159723e) by Andrew Coyle).

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use the word "magnet" a lot.  When I'm driving, I'm an idiot magnet.  When I'm at a party, I seem to be a bore magnet.  StackExchange is a nerd magnet.

This UI would be an error magnet.

I suppose "vortex" or "black hole" or "sucker" could replace "magnet."   This UI is a black hole of bad clicks.  This UI actively hunts down and sucks in errors.

Answer (score 3):

This UI is:

1. not user-friendly (specific)
2. overly complex
3. unintuitive
4. dangerous (general)

As a side note:
You mentioned you wanted to avoid criticism of the creator, but be aware the word you're asking for will be a word of opinion. In most cases, qualifiers can be used to fine-tune the intent of your word choice. Depending on the style and perspective of the writing, you may be able to use words of emotion to get more control of the overall message you are trying to convey.

Consider the change of intent as you read:

- This UI is unintuitive. *(declarative)*
- This UI may be unintuitive. *(suggestive)*
- This UI may be unintuitive to new users. *(informative)*
- I feel that this UI may be unintuitive. *(personal, suggestive)*
- I feel that this UI may be unintuitive to new users. *(personal, informative)*

Answer (score 2):

***inherently flawed***

> Inherent literally refers to something that is "stuck in" something else so firmly that they can't be separated. A plan may have an inherent flaw that will cause it to fail; a person may have inherent virtues that everyone admires. Since the flaw and the virtues can't be removed, the plan may simply have to be thrown out and the person will remain virtuous forever.

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inherent)

So if the UI is *inherently flawed* it refers to the design and not the designer.

Comment: I know the OP said that "flawed" was not adequate for their purpose, I think when accompanied by "inherently" it can work.

Comment: The term does refer to the design, but I disagree that this option makes no judgement of the designer. Whoever designed an inherently flawed UI did a damn poor job.

Comment: @NuclearWang ...of course that would be inferred...but not actually implied.

Answer (score 2):

A foolproof system is robust, in this context an antonym is **brittle**
Wikipedia: [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) "a system should behave in a way that most users will expect it to behave"

My description for the OP's situation is:
The UI **provokes mistakes**

Even stronger words are "hazardous" or "It's a trap"

Answer (score 1):

'Flawed' is strict opposite of foolproof, and would be the word used in the arena of safety critical software design for a confusing human-machine interface.

Strictly a 'flaw' becomes a 'fault' when the system state reaches it, and a 'failure' when the consequences of the fault are not managed by the system.

Correctly implementing the wrong behaviour is still a flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be looking for mine-field?

Cambridge defines it as `a situation or subject that is very complicated and full of hidden problems and dangers:`

`The UI is a minefield of mistakes for the users`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of that dialog I'd say "badly worded".

"Let the job finish" could mean two opposite things - allow it to be killed (finish prematurely, right now) or allow it to run to its normal conclusion.

Clearly, if "No" aborts, then the designer was thinking of the second one.  Hmm, I think.  You've got me at it now!

If he'd used "continue" instead it would be unambiguous.  Non-native speaker, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**flawed**

> ▶ adjective INFALLIBLE, dependable, reliable, trustworthy, certain,
>   sure, guaranteed, safe, sound, tried and tested; watertight, airtight,
>   flawless, perfect; informal sure-fire; formal efficacious. Opposites: **flawed**.

— Concise Oxford Thesaurus 2nd Ed.

The UI allows for [many or easily made] mistakes (i.e. error-prone) but at the same time this is not due to the designer. It seems like you want to write a politically correct sentence.

Try,

1. The UI is coincidentally (error prone / flawed).
2. The UI is unintentionally (error prone / flawed).

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a phrase that is concise, strong, and avoids implying criticism of the creator is a little tricky, since the more concise and strong you get, the more likely it is to sound like harsh criticism. And it's hard to find a way to soften it without being less concise or less strong  and specific.

That being said, my best attempt at a fusion of the three:

- This UI is *easy to misuse* ([misuse, verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misuse))
- This UI is *prone to misuse* ([misuse, noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misuse))

These are specific (emphasize the fact that users will not only be confused, but will likely make errors) and non-critical (state the problem plainly, "misuse" indicates that it works when used correctly -- with the caveat that there's no way to phrase this without implying that the design has room for improvement).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure it fits the sense you're using it in here, but along the lines of the comment by jberryman, and answers by KannE and Bobby-J: we also apply terms like *antipattern* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)) and *dark pattern* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern)) to situations like this.

> **antipattern**
> A design pattern that may be commonly used, but is ineffective or counterproductive in practice. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antipattern))
>
> **dark pattern:**
> A user interface that is intentionally designed to trick users into doing things, such as giving up more information, or agreeing to unfavourable terms. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dark_pattern))

This UI is (or employs) **an anti-pattern** because it inverts the logical action of the affirmative buttons.

To close the loop, asking the user to confirm the destructive action is, by itself, just *a pattern* for helping the user avoid accidental destructive actions.

Answer (score -2):

I just made up this phrase off the top of my head, but how about *failbait*?

"This UI is [likely to be the cause of frequent user error]."
"This UI is failbait."

Comment: Failbait would imply to me that it was intentionally designed to fail (cf. clickbait which is intentionally designed to draw clicks). I'm not sure that the question carries that implication.